# Why would a managed pointer on GC heap crash the JIT compiler?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, garbage-collection, clr

I've been reading the [**docs for the new C# 7.2 update**](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/csharp/reference-semantics-with-value-types), and I'm not sure I got the meaning of a specific part of the section about the `ref struct` declaration.
Here it is:

> [...] In addition, putting a managed pointer on the GC heap typically crashes at JIT time.

What does that mean exactly? Let's say I have something like this:

```
IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(float) * 100);
float* pt = (float*)ptr.ToPointer();
Parallel.For(0, 10, i => 
{ 
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) pt[i * 10 + j] = i * 10 + j;
});
```

Or another example:

```
float[,] m = new float[10, 10];
fixed (float* pt = m) // I know I could put this inside the lambda, but this
{                     // way the pointer should be captured by the closure
                      // and therefore end up on the GC heap
    Parallel.For(0, 10, i => 
    { 
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) pt[i * 10 + j] = i * 10 + j;
    });
}
```

I'm assuming in both these cases that `float*` pointer would be captured and be stored on the GC heap, inside the closure, so:

- Would either (or both) of these cases cause a problem?
- Is this what that paragraph was talking about, or was that a different situation?
- If this is the case, why would something like this cause the JIT compiler to crash?

Thanks!

Comment: What you have in your example is not managed pointer. Managed pointer is for example "ref something" parameter.

Comment: The "crash" is produced by the verifier built into the jitter.  Which enforces the rules documented in Ecma-335, chapter II.14.4.2 for managed pointers: "Managed pointers cannot be stored in static variables, array elements, or fields of
objects or value types".  It makes life for the garbage collector a lot easier.